# RPART model ignoring variable while fitting the model

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, rpart

When I am trying to fit a classification tree model using Survival~Sex+Pclass , it is not considering the Pclass and is only considering sex (when Survival, Sex, and Pclass are factored as shown in the code)no matter what the control parameter is specified.

Code:

```
library(titanic)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

train = titanic_train
titanic_train$Survived = factor(titanic_train$Survived)
titanic_train$Sex = factor(titanic_train$Sex)
titanic_train$Pclass = factor(titanic_train$Pclass)
ctrl=rpart.control(minsplit = 6, cp=0.001)
fit = rpart(Survived ~  Pclass + Sex , data = titanic_train,control=ctrl)
rpart.plot(fit)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V50YE.png]

Comment: it is not required that the optimal classification tree will use all of the variables in your model. if you just inserted random noise, you should be happy it is not a factor

Answer (score 1):

It really really doesn't want to split any further.  Even setting `cp = 0` doesn't do the trick (with `minsplit = 1`).  But `cp = -1` does, making the tree branch down to a leaf for each class.  (Whether that's desirable or not is another story...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an interesting observation since

- we know that *Pclass* is a highly informative variable,
- most other classification tree software will split further on *Pclass* (e.g. `tree::tree`, `partykit::ctree`, `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`, ...),
- the regression tree version of the exact same code (i.e. NOT converting *Survived* to a factor but keeping it numeric.) results in 4 leaves, even though the Gini impurity is identical to the variance loss function for 0/1 data.

Also difficult to explain why for `cp = 0` and `minsplit = 1` the resulting tree would not be the deepest possible.

Answer (score 1):

The *rpart* author allowed me to use his answer, which I paste below:

```
train <- titanic_train
names(train) <- tolower(names(train))  # I'm lazy

train$pclass <- factor(train$pclass)

fit1 <- rpart(survived ~ pclass + sex, data=train)
fit2 <- rpart(survived ~ pclass + sex, data=train, method="class")
fit1

n= 891 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 891 210.727300 0.3838384  
  2) sex=male 577  88.409010 0.1889081  
    4) pclass=2,3 455  54.997800 0.1406593 *
    5) pclass=1 122  28.401640 0.3688525 *
  3) sex=female 314  60.105100 0.7420382  
    6) pclass=3 144  36.000000 0.5000000 *
    7) pclass=1,2 170   8.523529 0.9470588 *

fit2
n= 891 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 891 342 0 (0.6161616 0.3838384)  
  2) sex=male 577 109 0 (0.8110919 0.1889081) *
  3) sex=female 314  81 1 (0.2579618 0.7420382) *
```

The issue: when you choose "classification" as the method,  either explicitly like I did above or implicitly by setting the outcome to a factor, you have declared that the loss function is a simple "correct/incorrect" for alive/dead.     For males, the survival rate is .189, which is < .5, so they class as 0.   The next split below gives rates of .14 and .37, both of which are < .5,  both are then treated as 0.   The second split did not improve the model, according to the criteria that you chose.  With or without it all males are a "0", so no need for the second split.

Ditto for the females:  the overall and the two subclasses are both >= .5, so the second split does not improve prediction, according to the criteria that you selected.

When I leave the response as continuous, then the final criteria is MSE, and the further splits are counted as an improvement.